# PYMC3: forrtl: error (200): program aborting due to control-C event

Tags: python, pymc3

I am new to python and pymc3. I am attempting to replicate the linear regression example given by PYMC3 document site https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/getting_started.html#A-Motivating-Example:-Linear-Regression. I am running anaconda 5.2, python 3.6.5 on windows 10. This also causes my console to freeze up and the command line disappears.

Can anyone help me understand this error?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Initialize random number generator
np.random.seed(123)

# True parameter values
alpha, sigma = 1, 1
beta = [1, 2.5]

# Size of dataset
size = 100

# Predictor variable
X1 = np.random.randn(size)
X2 = np.random.randn(size) * 0.2

# Simulate outcome variable
Y = alpha + beta[0]*X1 + beta[1]*X2 + np.random.randn(size)*sigma



import pymc3 as pm
print('Running on PyMC3 v{}'.format(pm.__version__))

basic_model = pm.Model()

with basic_model:

    # Priors for unknown model parameters
    alpha = pm.Normal('alpha', mu=0, sd=10)
    beta = pm.Normal('beta', mu=0, sd=10, shape=2)
    sigma = pm.HalfNormal('sigma', sd=1)

    # Expected value of outcome
    mu = alpha + beta[0]*X1 + beta[1]*X2

    # Likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations
    Y_obs = pm.Normal('Y_obs', mu=mu, sd=sigma, observed=Y)

map_estimate = pm.find_MAP(model=basic_model)

map_estimate

map_estimate = pm.find_MAP(model=basic_model, method='powell')

map_estimate


   with basic_model:
       # draw 500 posterior samples
        trace = pm.sample(500)


with basic_model:

    # instantiate sampler
    step = pm.Slice()

    # draw 5000 posterior samples
    trace = pm.sample(5000, step=step)

    pm.traceplot(trace);

    pm.summary(trace).round(2)
```

The error i receive:

```
Exception: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', 
Alloc(TensorConstant{(1,) of 0.0}, Shape_i{0}.0), '\n', 'Compilation failed 
(return status=3): ', '[Alloc(TensorConstant{(1,) of 0.0}, 
<TensorType(int64, scalar)>)]')
forrtl: error (200): program aborting due to control-C event
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
libifcoremd.dll    00007FFBD1A594C4  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
KERNELBASE.dll     00007FFC0098717D  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
KERNEL32.DLL       00007FFC02EF2774  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ntdll.dll          00007FFC043D0D51  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ERROR: The process "4828" not found.
forrtl: error (200): program aborting due to control-C event
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
libifcoremd.dll    00007FFBD1A594C4  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
KERNELBASE.dll     00007FFC0098717D  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
KERNEL32.DLL       00007FFC02EF2774  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ntdll.dll          00007FFC043D0D51  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

With pymc3 questions in general, your better to head to their [discourse](https://discourse.pymc.io/) page.

However, I was having a similar issue (not the exact same error message mind you) with pymc3 on windows. Try setting `njobs=1` in the sample function and see if that helps.

Update: The code above seems to compile fine on my machine, so maybe try updating pymc3/python to the newest versions

Answer (score -3):

It seems like you pressed "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>" when the program is still running, and terminated it. Try not to press "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>".